# How do I reference the length of a curve as a driver variable for the screw modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, drivers

I would like the screw setting to automatically change with the length of the curve to achieve a stretching effect. Here's an example of what I'm looking for. [image]

This was made by calculating the distance between the first and last empty. But as you can see it only references the direct distance between the two empties and ignores the actual length of the curve. [image]

Comment: Hello ! I would use one iteration of Screw and a Array modifier set to Fit Curve

Comment: @Gorgious That would create/delete screw iterations rather than changing the length of the screw

Comment: Oh right I didn't understand your question. you'll have to use a python script and add a function to the driver namespace. the information is not available directly to the drivers functions